# How to set several paths in VScodes Python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to set 2 interpreter Paths in VScode(Windows) for the Python extension.
I don't know how and I don't want to use .env files. I want to add Python 2.7 and 3.8

VScode settings.json:

```
...    
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\{myuser}\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe",
"python.showStartPage": false,
...
```

launch.json:

```
{
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
         {
             "name": "Python: Aktuelle Datei",
             "type": "python",
             "request": "launch",
             "program": "${file}",
             "console": "integratedTerminal",
         }
     ]
 }
```

I know that there is "python.autoComplete.extraPaths" but it didn't work.

Comment: Python 2.x is end of life, so it is meaningless to use it any more. The Microsoft Python extension also is designed to support a single Python interpreter at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The python extension can detect the python interpreter **automatically**. It will automatically look for interpreters in the following locations:

```
 1. Standard install paths such as /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /sbin, c:\\python27, c:\\python36, etc.
 2. Virtual environments located directly under the workspace (project) folder.
 3. Virtual environments located in the folder identified by the python.venvPath setting (see General settings), which can contain multiple virtual environments. The extension looks for virtual
```

and so on... You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) for more information.

**You can also [manually specify an interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) if Visual Studio Code does not locate it automatically.** like this: